# Can I use args1>args2 ? args1: args2 statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, comparator

I know that I can use conditional shortcut in Java, but is it transferable in JavaScript?
if not, what is the best way to do it?

below is my code:

```js
int minlen =s1.length<s2.length?s1.length :s2.length;
```

Comment: Yes you can do that (`var` instead of `int`), or `minlen = Math.min(s1.length, s2.length);`. It would probably have saved you some time if you had simply tried that in your browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes This works in Javascript too!
replace declaring variable 'int' to 'var'.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can also use ternary operator in JavaScript.

```js
var s1 = "lorem";
var s2 = "ips";
var minlen = s1.length < s2.length ? s1.length : s2.length;
console.log(minlen)
```